# Stack overflow (parameters: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000001046003F68). String

Tags: c++

I have a quite huge problem.
Whenever I compile the program with this argument "8 (enter) 4 0 2 (enter) 0 1 6 (enter) 2 3 7 (enter) 1 5 (enter) 6 5 (enter) 3 5 (enter) 7 5 (enter)", I got an error about stack overflow, and it shows this line of code in xstring: `_CONSTEXPR20_CONTAINER bool _Large_string_engaged() const noexcept {` 
My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
bool funcSprawdz(vector<string>& odp, string& por)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < odp.size(); i++)
    {
        if (odp[i] == por) return false;
    }
    return true;

}


string tempString="";
void func(vector<string>& myArray, vector<string>& odp, int szufladka)
{
    tempString = ""; 
    int numDoPrz;
    int rozmTab = myArray[szufladka].size();
    
         
         if (szufladka == 0)
         {
             tempString = "0";
             if (funcSprawdz(odp, tempString))
             {
                 odp.push_back(tempString);
             }         
         }
         else if(rozmTab == 1)
         {
             tempString = myArray[szufladka].at(0);
             if (funcSprawdz(odp, tempString))
             {
                 odp.push_back(tempString);
             }
         }
         else if (rozmTab == 3 && szufladka != 0)
         {
             numDoPrz = static_cast<int>(myArray[szufladka].at(2) - 48);
             func(myArray, odp, numDoPrz);
             tempString = myArray[szufladka].at(2);
             if (funcSprawdz(odp, tempString))
             {
                 odp.push_back(tempString);
             }
             tempString = myArray[szufladka].at(0);
             if (funcSprawdz(odp, tempString))
             {
                 odp.push_back(tempString);
             }

         }
         else if (rozmTab == 5)
         {
             numDoPrz = static_cast<int>(myArray[szufladka].at(4) - 48);
             func(myArray, odp, numDoPrz);
             tempString = myArray[szufladka].at(4);
             if (funcSprawdz(odp, tempString))
             {
                 odp.push_back(tempString);
             }
             tempString = myArray[szufladka].at(0);
             if (funcSprawdz(odp, tempString))
             {
                 odp.push_back(tempString);
             }
             numDoPrz = static_cast<int>(myArray[szufladka].at(2) - 48);
             func(myArray, odp, numDoPrz);  
             tempString = myArray[szufladka].at(2);
             if (funcSprawdz(odp, tempString))
             {
                 odp.push_back(tempString);
             }
             tempString = myArray[szufladka].at(0);
             if (funcSprawdz(odp, tempString))
             {
                 odp.push_back(tempString);
             }
         }     
}
int main() {
    string tempStr;
    vector<string>myArray;
    vector<string>odp;
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        getline(cin, tempStr);
        myArray.push_back(tempStr);
    }
    sort(myArray.begin() + 1, myArray.end());
    for (int i = 1; i < myArray.size(); i++)
    {
        func(myArray, odp, i);
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < odp.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << odp[i] << " ";
    }

}
```

But (to my surprise) it doesn't happen when I use as argument some other combinations like: "4 (enter) 1 0 (enter) 2 0 (enter) 3 1 2 (enter)" of course after changing

`for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)`
into
`for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)`

EDIT: Task of my code:
Consider an academic program that consists of NN courses. Every course is designated by an integer index from 0 to N-1.

Some courses have others as prerequisites. For example, if course 2 is a prerequisite of course 3 you must finish course 2 before enrolling in course 3.

You can attend only a single course at a time. Build a schedule to complete all courses in a linear sequence and to satisfy all prerequisites for every course.

If more than one variant of possible schedule exists, use the schedule where courses with smaller indices are finished first.
**Input:**
The first line contains a positive integer representing the number of courses in the academic program.

Each additional line describes the prerequisites of a given course as a space-delimited set of indices. Every set of prerequisites has at least two indices.

The first index in the set denotes the course for which a prerequisite exists. All other indices designate which courses are required for the first.

**Output:**
A schedule containing a space-delimited list of courses, in the order of their attendance

EDIT NR.2 :
So I changed my code a little, but still I get error when I try to give argument like: "8 (enter)
4 0 2 (enter)
0 1 6 (enter)
2 3 7 (enter)
1 5 (enter)
6 5 (enter)
3 5 (enter)
7 5 (enter)"
What changed:
from:

```
func(myArray, odp, numDoPrz);
```

to

```
if (numDoPrz != szufladka)
            {
                func(tablica, odp, numDoPrz);
            }
```

And I have put if statement on start of func() function

```
    if (odp.size() <= tablica.size())
```

Comment: Have you tried to look at the call stack in the debugger after the crash?

Comment: You're calling `func` recursively. You need to ensure/verify that at least one of the parameters in the recursive call is different than any previous call, otherwise the recursion never ends until you run out of stack space. In your case, this would be the last parameter (`szufladka`).

Comment: Note: contents of call stack may be a mess after a stack overflow. Great information source if it isn't, though.

Comment: Something like that would be okay? 
`
if (numDoPrz != szufladka)

             {

                 func(tablica, odp, numDoPrz);

             }

`